# Which style of CSS formatting you would prefer to use if we are using Version control?

Tags: css, git, svn, version-control

I'm going to use version control first time and I read somewhere that Single line CSS is not a good idea for version control

```
.footer li h3 { margin: 0 0 6px; font-weight: bold; display: inline; color: #e92e2e; }
.footer li h3 a { font-weight: normal; font-size: 1em; color: #e92e2e; }
```

Which format you would prefer?

Is this below formatting good to use with version control

```
.footer li h3 {
    margin: 0 0 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    color: #e92e2e; }

    .footer li h3 a {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #e92e2e; }
```

Comment: I don't think version control systems know anything about the file contents except the comparishon so I doubt it matters.. but hence version control is for sharing a project and improving such I'd prefer readability above all? whatever suits you

Comment: The main concern as far as version control, and probably the reason you heard this, is that you won't be able to easily read what changes were made if everything is on the same line. See Doozer's answer. Aside: I've never seen anyone write CSS like example 2...

Answer (score 3):

From a standpoint of readability, Yes, the formatting you show makes more sense on multiple-lines because you'll be able to easily see the difference between 2 versions if a new attribute is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with other people on the same code, readability is the #1 most important thing you should focus on in your code (aside from making the code work, of course). A close second is using comments EVERYWHERE. This is just my opinion, of course some people might prefer comments over readability. Even if you're not working with anybody else, it's still very important to write readable code, in case another developer takes over the project in the future.

To answer your question, I prefer the second format, and I guess that most programmers would agree.

Comment: Although I don't recommend it personally: version one (each selector on one line) can be more readable if the lines are not too long. Vertical space is also important to readability.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - yes but many times we can have multiple selector and properties inside.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I agree with your last statement, however, in the case of CSS, I tend to unintentionally skip over things when it's laid out horizontally like that. Imagine if you wrote out your entire grocery list in a horizontal fashion... it just makes it a lot harder to follow. Plus, if it's laid out vertically, my eyes can go right to the attribute I'm looking for. If it's horizontal I have to really look for it.

Comment: I meant readability in source files. Sometimes your example 1 is easier to read when viewing the file as a whole. @bricker: I mostly agree with you, but I have to say that I write my grocery notes very compact so I can carry a smaller piece of paper. For instance, 10 selectors with one property each can be easier to read if each one is on it's own line, by itself. Would upvote but I think you missed the context of version control (which we're also not talking about in these comments).

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Yes it make the scrolling shorter but very long lines are hard to read. Multiple line are always easy to scan. and the good thing is we can also add any comment for a property.

Comment: JitendraVyas: If you know these things, why is it you're asking this question? You failed to link to where you heard that "Single line CSS is not a good idea" but you seem to agree with it, so what is your concern?  @bricker: Have a +1

Comment: @WesleyMurch - because I wanted to know if single line has any problem with Version control. because some developer of my team like single line css.

Comment: @JitendraVyas There is no issue using single-line CSS with version control.

Answer (score 1):

In Git you can easily do a `word diff` and quickly find changes within a line.

What you should really be looking at is making sure the CSS is readable. Use the format that your team is comfortable with. Make sure everyone does the same. See what the CSS community does. I don't think a version control system should be the reason you choose a format.

And of course, if you want compressed / minified CSS ( which is not exacly what you are asking ), it has to be part of build process and the file checked in should not be minified